# Loading excel sheet data into sql table using stored proc

Tags: sql, excel

I want to extract data from a excel workbook sheet saved onto a file location. There are month columns and related products sold value for each month in the excel file, This needs to be loaded onto a sql table that has productname and month been a unique combination. **productnames are not duplicated in the excel file**

So excel file have column headings Product  Jul-17   Aug-17  Sep-17 upto Jun-18 as column headings. In a row the data will be product code, qty sold for each month for that product.

In SQL table would have columns

```
Product    Month    SoldQTY
A1         Jul-17     25
A1         Aug-17     60
A1         Sep-17     33
```

What's the sql to achieve this in the stored proc? 
Please help!!

Comment: `mysql`<>`sql-server` Only tag the RDBMS you are using. I have removed the conflicting tags for you, please correct them. Thanks,

Comment: Have you done any research? If so, what are your findings?

Comment: Thank you fixing up the formatting. I know how to load excel data to sql table. Just want to know sql to do this particular one?

Comment: Have you tried `unpivot`? https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/unpivot-columns-power-query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098

Comment: Very new to this so no. How will UNPIVOT work in this. can you type how the sql will look like? Thanks

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: sql server 2016 stored procedure that'll go like insert into ........ and then select ......................... from OPENSOURCE